# Identity with scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra

In one proof of some theorem regarding normal distribution there is used I think an idenitity which states

$$ (ABy,By)=(B^{-1}ABy,y)$$
where A is symetric and positive, B is orthogonal and y is a vector.

Can someone explain to me why is it so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume $(\cdot, \cdot) $ denotes the scalar product. An orthogonal matrix $B$ preserves the scalar product by definition, i.e.
$$(Bx,By)=(x,y).$$
Since $B^{-1}$ is also orthogonal, then
$$(ABy, By) = (B^{-1}ABy,B^{-1}By)=(B^{-1}ABy,y).$$

Answer (score 4):

It follows easily from
1. $(u,v)=u^tv$, where $u^t$ is the transpose of $u$,
2. $(CD)^t=D^tC^t$,
3. $C$ symmetric iff $C=C^t$, and
4. $C$ orthogonal iff $C^t=C^{-1}$.

Comment: The fact that $A$ is symmetric is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent definition of an orthogonal matrix is one for which $(Bv, Bw) = (v, w)$ for all vectors $v$ and $w$. You can check that if $B$ is orthogonal, then $B^{-1}$ exists and is orthogonal. Can you work it out from there?